# multi select with check boxes using reactjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, checkbox, multi-select, jsx

hi iam trying to implement multiselect with checkboxes(for each value populated in should proceed by check box for selecting the value).
when i am trying with simple select, all the list of values are displaying as expected.( nthis is for confirmation that the list of values are being populated to view from the controller as expected). while iam replacing the select with multi select tag the list of values are not getting populated in the box, instead nothing is coming in the box. please help me with the exact code.

similar example with bootstap is given in the below link.https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-multiselect/pulls

Comment: Hi i am trying to implement multiselect list with check boxes using react-bootstrap-multiselect api am able to populate the checkboxes But event handling is not happening. example code lilke this:

Comment: would you mind to share the code where you are populating the multiselect component?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending data in this format [{value: 'one', selected: true}, {value: 'two'}]